# sebp/elk logstash cannot receive data with Kafka

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, logstash, apache-kafka

I'm using the Docker ELK container from https://hub.docker.com/r/sebp/elk/, according to the logstash-logs everything is fine and running.

Now I try to receive data from Kafka and write into ES with the following config:

```
input {
    kafka {
        topic_id => "collectortopic"
        zk_connect => "172.17.0.2:2181"
        type => "kafka-input"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["172.17.0.4:9200"]
        codec => json
    }
    stdout {
        codec => json
    }
}
```

But anything in my setup seems to be wrong, because I cannot receive any data. There's neither any output from Logstash in the console nor any data in Kibana, because there is no logstash index created, which should be the default behavior according to the plugin docs.

My Kafka setup is fine, because I can send and receive data with other applications, zk_connect is correct too, because otherwise I get exceptions ...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Kafka 0.9.1, Logstash 2.3.3, ES 2.3.3

Comment: if this is still not working can you add your docker run commands for both elk and kafka?  i believe you are not setting the ip's properly which is causing your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the Logstash server can communicate with Kafka and Elasticsearch?

You can use this:

For Elasticsearch:

```
curl 172.17.0.4:9200
```

And if you should have an answer like:

```
{
  "name" : "inf01-log-els",
  "cluster_name" : "inf01-log-els",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.2.1",
    "build_hash" : "d045fc29d1932bce18b2e65ab8b297fbf6cd41a1",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-03-09T09:38:54Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.4.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

For kafka, you can check with this:

```
telnet 172.17.0.2 2181
```

I had a few ELK problems coming from that.

Comment: How can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess Logstash's is failing to parse whatever you are sending. Is it valid JSON? Have you check for log errors?

Comment: Yes, the JSON sended is valid and there are no errors in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case where Kafka is running in another container I had to set     KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME to an IP address instead of localhost.

Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating logstash-input-kafka plugin version to anything > 3.x.x?
According to [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html), Kafka 0.9+ is supported by plugin versioned 3.x+. Logstash 2.x still comes by default with plugin version 2.x.